# how to flatten a itertools.product

Tags: python, tuples, flatten

I have an itertools.product of three sets that looks like this:

input:

```
t1 = set(['R'])
t2 = set(['Y'])
t3 = set(['A', 'C', 'H', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'Y'])

list(itertools.product(t1, t2, t3))
```

output:

```
[('R', 'Y', 'A'), ('R', 'Y', 'C'), ('R', 'Y', 'H'), ('R', 'Y', 'M'), ('R', 'Y', 'T'), ('R', 'Y', 'W'), ('R', 'Y', 'Y')]
```

But if I try and flatten it, it makes one long list, but what I want is this:

```
[('RYA'), ('RYC'), ('RYH'), ('RYM'), ('RYT'), ('RYW'), ('RYY')]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: sure, it doesnt really matter. Its more a question of the flattening of the product list.

Comment: This is not a question about `itertools` or about Cartesian products, because the code that creates the list works properly, and because the question would be the same no matter how that list was created. Removed those tags.

Answer (score 8):

Join each tuple in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(t1, t2, t3)]
['RYH', 'RYA', 'RYC', 'RYY', 'RYT', 'RYM', 'RYW']
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect. Thanks!